# Typescript - How to change type of axios response when modified interceptor to return config.data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, frontend

## Here is the code

```
const fetcher = Axios.create()

fetcher.interceptors.response.use(config=>{
  return config.data
})
```

## Problem is

Type of `fetcher.get('...')` is AxiosInstance, but it's actually AxiosInstance.data type

So how could I change the type correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Write the types somewhere, e.g. src/types/axios/axios.d.ts.

```
import axios from 'axios'

declare module 'axios' {
  export interface AxiosInstance {
    request<T = any> (config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    get<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    delete<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    head<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    post<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    put<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
    patch<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T>;
  }
}
```

2. Update your tsconfig.json, e.g.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types",
        "./src/types/",
    ]
  }
}
```

3. Now you can use `fetcher.get<DataType>('...')` and you should get the response of a type mentioned.

This solution may work! Also review the [this thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1510) to learn more!
[Solution Ref](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1510#issuecomment-525382535)

Answer (score 7):

It is [not necessary](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1510#issuecomment-396894600) to redefine the module.

Assuming your interceptor does `response => response.data` and a server response like:

```
{
  book: { id: 42 }
}
```

This should be enough:

```
type Book = {
    id: number
}

type ResponseContainer = {
    book: Book
}

request.post<unknown, ResponseContainer>('/api')
    .then(({ book }) => console.log(book.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one as in [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L140)

```
fetcher.get<DataType>('...')
```

EX: if it's returning a number

```
fetcher.get<number>('...')
```

Comment: Thank you. Still whatever type I wrote inside fetcher.get<...> it return AxiosInstance, because that type only describe the data structure of AxiosInstance